# Dynamic creation of class with descriptors based on object variables

Tags: python

I want to dynamically (at runtime) create a python class that mimics a class but changes the vars to descriptors.

For example if I have:

```py
class base:
    pass

def get_custom_class(obj):
    pass #need to do something here, return a class with descriptors for vars(obj)

t = base()
t.a = 1
t.b = '2'
vars(t) # {'a': 1, 'b': '2'}
custom_t = get_custom_class(t)
custom_t.a #calls a descriptor.__get__ in custom_t's class that gets t.a
custom_t.b = '3' #calls a descriptor.__set__ that set's t.a (and will check type).
t.b    #'3'
```

I need to do something in `get_custom_class` that dynamically will create a `<class 'type'>` with the needed descriptors, and then instantiate it once to return an object that has attributes that are descriptors (using the latest Python).

Comment: What would be the point of this class? You could probably use `unittest.mock.Mock` to wrap the object.

Comment: Python supports "metaclasses" which are classes that create other classes, so check them out — there are also many question on this site about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type(name, bases, attrs)` to create a class with attributes of attrs.  Then you can instantiate this class as needed; you need to instantiate it to get descriptors to work.
So the trick is just to fill a dict with keys of the vars and values of a descriptor object.

```py
class your_custom_descriptor:
    def __init__(self, obj, var):
        self._obj = obj
        self._var = var
    def __get__(self, o, otype=None):
        print(f'in __get__ {self._obj}.{self._var}={self._obj.__dict__[self._var]}')
        return self._obj.__dict__[self._var]
    def __set__(self, o, value):
        self._obj.__dict__[self._var] = value
        print(f'in __set__ {self._obj}.{self._var}={self._obj.__dict__[self._var]}')


class base:
    pass

def get_custom_class(your_orig_obj):
    attrs = dict()
    for var in vars(your_orig_obj):
        attrs[var]=your_custom_descriptor(your_orig_obj, var)
    custom_class = type('custom_class', (object, ), attrs)
    return custom_class()

t = base()
t.a = 1
t.b = '2'
r = base()
r.c = 'a'
print(vars(t)) # {'a': 1, 'b': '2'}
print(vars(r))
custom_t = get_custom_class(t)
custom_r = get_custom_class(r)
print(custom_t.a) #calls a descriptor.__get__ in custom_t's class that gets t.a
custom_t.b = '3' #calls a descriptor.__set__ that set's t.a (and will check type).
print(t.b)    #'3'
print(custom_r.c)
print(custom_r.a) #AttributeError, r didn't have an attribute a so custom_r doesn't
```